# Inconsistency between gaussian_kde and density integral sum

Tags: python, numpy, kernel-density

Can one explain why after estimation of kernel density

```
d = gaussian_kde(g[:,1])
```

And calculation of integral sum of it:

```
x = np.linspace(0, g[:,1].max(), 1500)
integral = np.trapz(d(x), x)
```

I got resulting integral sum completely different to 1:

```
print integral
Out: 0.55618
```

Comment: assuming g[:,1] is non-negative

Comment: Also the estimated Guassian kernal will extend past `g[:,1].max()` as the Gaussian distribution has an infinite support. Try extending both boundaries of `x` by the range of the data in `g[:,1]`.

Comment: with x = np.linspace(g[:,1].min(), g[:,1].max(), 1500) the result has changed unsignificantly: 0.55642

Comment: Try: `rang=g[:,1].max() - g[:,1].min()`, `x = np.linspace(g[:,1].min() - rang, g[:,1].max() + rang, 1500)`

Comment: That's helped. After density estimation the support range occurs to be larger than initial data range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comment, this is an issue with kernel density support. The Gaussian kernel has infinite support. Even fit on data with a specific range the range of the Gaussian kernel will be from negative to positive infinity. That being said the large majority of the density will lie within a range reasonably around the range of the fitted data.

If you would like a Gaussian kernel fitted within the range of your original data, you can fit a truncated Gaussian kernel by truncating the kernel and re-normalizing the truncated portion to integrate to 1, but I am not sure if that is what you want here. You can also truncate to a non-negative Gaussian kernel with similar logic.